# Splitting an element of Array and requesting "length" returning an error

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I was attempting to split an element (which is an Array) of an Array, and then access that array's length.

A sample input could be: "He walks. She walks.".

My code (with unrelated parts removed) is:

```
    function image(input, str) {
                let nos = str.split(".");
                let sub = [];
                let words = [];
                let ret = [];
                let isNoun = function (word, zzVal, zVal) {
                    let letters = word;
                    letters = letters.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/gi, "");
                    //if (input[z - 1])
                    letters = letters.split("");
                    return letters.join("");
                }
                for ( let zz = 0; zz < nos.length; zz++ ) {
                                ret[zz] = [];
                                if ( nos[ zz ] !== "" ) {
                                    sub.push( nos[ zz ] );
                                }
                                for ( let b = 0; b < sub.length; b++ ) {
                                                 words.push((sub[ b ].split(" ").filter(e => e !== "")));
                                    }
                                    alert( words );
                                 for (let z = 0; z < words[ zz ].length; z++) {
                                                let n = input[(zz * words[ zz ].length) + z].length;
                                                let x = 1;
                                                let y = 1;
                                                let dmn = [x, y];
                                                while ((x * y) < n) {
                                                                 if (n % 2 == 0) {
                                                                        x++;
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        x += 2;
                                                                    }
                                                                    y = n / x;
                                                                    if (y == 1 || !Number.isInteger(x)) {
                                                                        x = 2;
                                                                        y = 2;
                                                                        while ((x * y) < (n + 1)) {
                                                                                        y++;
                                                                                        x = (n + 1) / y;
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                    dmn = [x, y];
                                                    }
                                            let a = 0;
                                            ret[zz][z] = [];
                                                    for (let b = 0; b < y; b++) {
                                                                    ret[zz][z][b] = [];
                                                                    for (let c = 0; c < x; c++) {
                                                                                     ret[zz][z][b][c] = input[z][a];
                                                                                     a++;
                                                            }
                                            }
                                        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<div id='" + zz + "' class='sentence'><div id='" + zz + "-bottom" + "'></div><div id='" + zz + "-line'></div><div id='" + zz + "-top'></div></div>";
                                        alert(isNoun(str.split(" ")[z], zz, z));
                                        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<table id='" + zz + "-" + z + "' class='word'></table>";
                                    for (let a = 0; a < y; a++) {
                                                        document.getElementById(zz + "-" + z).innerHTML += "<tr id='" + zz + "-" + z + "-" + a + "'></tr>";
                                                        for (let b = 0; b < x; b++) {
                                                             if (Number(ret[zz][z][a][b])) {
                                                                                document.getElementById(zz + "-" + z + "-" + a).innerHTML += "<td id='" + zz + "-" + z + "-" + a + "-" + b + "'></td>";
                                                             } else {
                                                                 document.getElementById(zz + "-" + z + "-" + a).innerHTML += "<td id='" + zz + "-" + z + "-" + a + "-" + b + "' style='background: #eee;'></td>";
                                                             }
                                                        }
                                    }
                                }
     }
}
```

This gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

My desired output is an Array, which, if `image(null, "He walks. She walks.")` is: `[["He", "walks"], ["She", "walks"]]`.

Comment: what is the error massage?

Comment: Your code as posted is working (if a little awkward), [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4z9jqofm/). Possible the error lies in the 'unrelated parts'.

Comment: @Nur The error is :

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: can you give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?
it looks like you are trying to list the words of given string?

Answer (score 0):

Because your last question is not clear and you updating the output that you want, here is the solution that maybe you can try

```
function image(input, str) {
let nos = str.split(".");
var newArray = [] //create newArray from (.) symbol
for (let i = 0; i < nos.length; i++){
    if (nos[i] != ""){
        newArray.push([nos[i]])
    }
}
console.log(newArray) //[ [ 'He walks' ], [ ' She walks' ] ]
//you can see the (space) behind S in She walks
//lets remove it

var secondArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
    // this metode will help you to push array that aren`t has space
    secondArray.push((newArray[i][0].split(" ").filter(e => e !== "")))
    }
console.log(secondArray) // [ [ 'He', 'walks' ], [ 'She', 'walks' ] ]
}

image(null, "He walks. She walks.")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after substituting my old code for your new code, the problem still occurs. I am including most of the "unrelated parts".

Comment: I update my answer, hope it working well now @FornaxI.

Comment: I implemented your solution, and it still returns the error. I modified and extended your solution to no avail. I am updating the MRE to exactly what I have (no "unrelated parts" removed).

Comment: I'm so sorry, i just can help you as far is the input is image(null, "He walks. She walks.") then give output [["He", "walks"], ["She", "walks"]]. You can try my code in javascript runner program, it will give that output @FornaxI.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function image(input, str) {

  // Remove dots
  let nos = str.split(".")
  
  // Remove empty space after dots
  for (let i=0;i<nos.length;i++){
    if(nos[i][0]===" "){
      nos[i]=nos[i].substring(1)
    }
  }
  
  // Remove empty array element
  nos=nos.filter(item=>item!=="")
  
  // Console log array elements length
  for (let i=0;i<nos.length;i++){   
    console.log(nos[i],nos[i].length)
  }
  
}

image(null, "He walks. She walks.");
```